# Forcing Right to Left Text

Tags: html

I have to display a collection of English and Aramaic text in a right to left order in html.  The text is separated into phrases which look like the example below and the font for the Aramaic is not a unicode font (and I can't use a unicode font) consequently the browser is interpreting the text as all western text, and therefore left to right even though I have designated the paragraph DIR="RTL".

The bracketed sections need to still be left to right in the order within the brackets, but the order of the overall text needs to be oriented so the first bracketed group is to the right of the page, and the next group is after that, etc.

In this example, the first bracketed group on the left needs to be first on the right.

```
"1   ( the beginning, In the Origin, at the origin ) tysrb ( a son, The Son, son ) arb ( God, of God, The God ) ahla  ty ( Heaven, the heavens, the Heavens ) ayms "
```

How do I tell the browser that the text that is not in brackets is to be treated like unicode right to left text when it thinks it is western, left to right.

Is there a way that I can tell the browser to treat the specific True Type Hebrew font that I have as a right to left font and subsequently to break the text direction there?

Comment: What would this look like? Can you draw a simple picture?

Comment: ‏‎‎(God )‎ ahla ( created)‎ arb‎ ( In the Origin )‎ tysrb .. {Read From Here}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to force the direction using bdo (bidi override) markup:

```
<p dir=rtl>
<bdo dir=rtl>
"1 <bdo dir=ltr>( the beginning, In the Origin, at the origin )</bdo> tysrb
<bdo dir=ltr>( a son, The Son, son )</bdo> arb
<bdo dir=ltr>(  God, of God, The God )</bdo> ahla  ty  
<bdo dir=ltr>( Heaven, the heavens, the Heavens )</bdo> ayms "
</bdo>
</p>
```

The dir attribute as such (or the direction property in CSS) affects the writing direction basically only for directionally neutral text. Latin letters have inherent left to right directionality, so you need to do override.

If you use spaces after “(” and before “)”, make the spaces non-breaking (use U+00A0, as the reference `&nbsp;` if needed), to prevent a parenthesis from being split from the enclosed text (this is especially relevant in RTL writing).

Comment: That works great, many thanks.  I will now have fun adding the code to my 300,000 line document...... thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS [`direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/direction) property.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

FOR **HTML4**

```
<Q lang="he" dir="rtl">...a Hebrew quotation...</Q>
```

REFER http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html

FOR **HTML5**

```
<span dir=rtl>PURPLE PIZZA</span>
```

REFER http://annevankesteren.nl/2010/11/html5-bidirectional-text

Answer (score 0):

you  can use the `direction` property in CSS or by placing the `dir` attribute in your HTML codes.

```
#LeftSide {
 direction: ltr;
 }
 #RightSide {
 direction: rtl;
  }
```